# How to consume .NET dataset in Delphi?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, delphi, delphi-5

I want to consume a .NET web-service that will accept SQL statement, for example: `select * from my_table order by name` and will return that dataset to my Delphi `ClientDataSet` / disconnected `TADODataSet`, and will display the result in the TDBGrid.

Part 2) After I update a single record I want to be able to update the .NET dataset via a webservice.

How can I do that? (Code Please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) .Net datasets uses XML to transfer it's data, so you can read them as XML then convert them to Delphi Dataset, Look at these articles

[Use ADO.NET Datasets in Delphi](http://www.agnisoft.com/soap/dotnetsoap.htm)

[Working with .NET data in Delphi](http://www.gekko-software.nl/DotNet/Art08.htm)

2) As I understand you will using Web services, so it will be better to add an update method to your service and call it to update the data.

One note, IMO, sending raw SQL to web services as the way you would like to use is a bad design, I prefer you to do define your business logic as group of methods, then call them as your application needs.

Also you can use Delphi Prism for more easier and better .Net integration

Comment: Thanks. I already read these articles before posting my Q. the first one states: `This transformation is very specific to this particular service and XML schema`. the second one uses `TGekkoDotNetDataSet`. I'm looking for a generics method to to display ANY dataset. I cannot use Delphi Prism.

Comment: Try to return the result as generic xml and parse in Delphi.